# Node.JS read a string line by line

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am working with Node.Js and have the below block of code to pull a string from a Database location, strips off certain junk and sets it up to be uniform, so I can update another table with this information later.

```
jsUpdateCon.query('SELECT FileContent FROM codeFile WHERE ID = ?',[msg[1]], function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    str = result[0].FileContent;
    var firstInstance = str.search(/=/) + 2;
    var lastInstance = str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    str = str.substring(firstInstance, lastInstance);
    str = str.replace(/\\n\\/g, "");
    str = str.replace(/\#(.*)/g, "");
    str = str.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n");
    str = str.replace(/snippet /g, "\nsnippet ");
    str = str.replace(/^(?:\t)/gm, "");

    console.log(str);
});
```

Here is a sample of the output from `console.log(str);`

```
snippet cfabort
<cfabort>

snippet cfargument
<cfargument name=\"${1:ArgName}\" type=\"${2:any}\" default=\"${3:DefaultValue}\" hint=\"${4:hint about this argument}\">

snippet cfbreak
<cfbreak>

snippet cfcase
<cfcase value=\"${1:${SELECTED_TEXT:<!--- code --->}}\">
        ${0}
</cfcase>

snippet cfcatch
<cfcatch>
        ${0}
</cfcatch>

snippet cfcatch:type
<cfcatch type=\"${1:any}\">
        ${0}
</cfcatch>

snippet cfcomponent
<cfcomponent>
        ${0:<!--- code --->}
</cfcomponent>

snippet cfcontent
<cfcontent deleteFile=\"${1:no}\" file=\"${2:filename}\" reset=\"${3:yes}\" type=\"${4:fileType}\" variable=\"${5:variableName}\">

snippet cfcontinue
<cfcontinue>

snippet cfdefaultcase
<cfdefaultcase>

snippet cfdirectory:c
<cfdirectory directory=\"${1:pathToDirectory}\" action=\"${2:copy}\" destination=\"${3:destinationPath}\">

snippet cfdirectory:cr
<cfdirectory directory=\"${1:pathToDirectory}\" action=\"${2:create}\" >

snippet cfdirectory:d
<cfdirectory directory=\"${1:pathToDirectory}\" action=\"${2:delete}\" recurse=\"${3:yes|no}\">

snippet cfdirectory:l
<cfdirectory directory=\"${1:pathToDirectory}\" action=\"${2:list}\" name=\"${3:nameOfOutputSet}\" recurse=\"${4:yes|no}\" sort=\"${3:asc|desc}\" >

snippet cfdirectory:r
<cfdirectory directory=\"${1:pathToDirectory}\" action=\"${2:rename}\" newDirectory=\"${3:newNameforDirectory}\">

snippet cfdump
<cfdump var=\"

snippet cfelse
<cfelse>
    ${0:<!--- code --->}
```

I am now needing to parse this string to insert into a database table.

Any line beginning with snippet[space] (such as "snippet cfabort") -> insert into keyboardShortcuts.keyShort such as "cfabort"(removing the snippet[space]).

Every line after (excluding the blank line between groups) -> insert into keyboardShortcuts.snippet such as "<cfabort>" keeping formatting of the group.

And then breaking on a blank line to start the next row in the DB table with the next snippet.

Do I use the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) from NodeJs?  This appears to only use a file stream not a string in memory.

Do I do use something else?  What is the best way to accomplish this?

---

Current Working Code with Abdullah Shahin's answer:

```
jsUpdateCon.query('SELECT FileContent FROM codeFile WHERE ID = ?',[msg[1]], function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;

    str = result[0].FileContent;
    var firstInstance = str.search(/=/) + 2;
    var lastInstance = str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    str = str.substring(firstInstance, lastInstance);
    str = str.replace(/\\"/g, "\"");
    str = str.replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
    str = str.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;");
    str = str.replace(/\\n\\/g, "");
    str = str.replace(/^\#(.*)/gm, "");
    str = str.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n");
    str = str.replace(/^(?:\t)/gm, "");
    str = str.trim();

    str = str.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"");

    var object = {};
    var tempArray = str.split("\n");
    var currentObj = "";
    for(var i=0; i<tempArray.length;i++){
        if(/snippet /g.test(tempArray[i])){
            currentObj = tempArray[i].replace(/snippet /g, "");
            object[currentObj] = "";
        } else {
            object[currentObj] += tempArray[i];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps, this code will parse it into an object, all snippets are the keys and you can find all values for a specific snippet match for its key

```
    var object = {};
    text = text.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"");
    var array = text.split("\n");
    var currentObj = "";
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(/snippet /g.test(array[i]))
        {
            currentObj = array[i].replace(/snippet /g,"");
            object[currentObj] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            object[currentObj] += array[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(object)
```

this is the output

```
{
    cfabort: '<cfabort>',
    cfargument: '<cfargument name=\\"${1:ArgName}\\" type=\\"${2:any}\\" default=\\"${3:DefaultValue}\\" hint=\\"${4:hint about this argument}\\">',
    cfbreak: '<cfbreak>',
    cfcase: '<cfcase value=\\"${1:${SELECTED_TEXT:<!--- code --->}}\\">        ${0}</cfcase>',
    cfcatch: '<cfcatch>        ${0}</cfcatch>',
    'cfcatch:type': '<cfcatch type=\\"${1:any}\\">        ${0}</cfcatch>',
    cfcomponent: '<cfcomponent>        ${0:<!--- code --->}</cfcomponent>',
    cfcontent: '<cfcontent deleteFile=\\"${1:no}\\" file=\\"${2:filename}\\" reset=\\"${3:yes}\\" type=\\"${4:fileType}\\" variable=\\"${5:variableName}\\">',
    cfcontinue: '<cfcontinue>',
    cfdefaultcase: '<cfdefaultcase>'
}
```

Comment: problem is like snippet catch some of the Values cover multiple lines so it wouldn't work even/odd

Comment: object is not defined

Comment: add var object = {}; and its solved, I updated the answer dude